# How to reproduce an error caused by sqlalchemy session caching

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, race-condition

I'm trying to reproduce a bug locally which I think is caused by a race condition where an update is relying on stale data (due to `synchronize_session=False`), essentially something like the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Boolean, CheckConstraint
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

# change this to your actual postgres url
db_string = "postgres://max:steve@localhost/test"

db = create_engine(db_string)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users4'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    deleted = Column(Boolean)
    super_user = Column(Boolean, CheckConstraint('NOT (super_user AND deleted)', name='check1'))


Base.metadata.create_all(db)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Session()
session.autoflush = False

# Create a user
session.add(User(id=1, deleted=False, super_user=False))

# Delete that user
session.query(User).filter(User.id == 1).update(
    {'deleted': True}, synchronize_session=False)

# Make all non-deleted users into super users
# Will violate the CHECK constraint if it's the previous query hasn't 
# been flushed
session.query(User).filter(User.deleted == False).update({'super_user': True})
```

Is there a way I can force sqlalchemy to use the cached session (maybe through mocking or some such) so that this code will raise violate the constraint and raise an `IntegrityError`?

The [docs for `synchronize_session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) say that

> ... updated objects may still remain in the session with stale values on their attributes, which can lead to confusing results.

This is the situation that I want to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

The last update query does not utilize the stale session data.  I think a case like this, where logic acts on the stale attributes will trigger the check constraint when a flush finally does occur:

```
# Create a user
user1 = User(id=1, deleted=False, super_user=False)
session.add(user1)


# Delete that user
session.query(User).filter(User.id == 1).update(
    {'deleted': True}, synchronize_session=False)


# Make all non-deleted users into super users
# Will violate the CHECK constraint if it's the previous query hasn't 
# been flushed
if not user1.deleted:
    user1.super_user = True

session.flush()
```